# How to set a click listener on an image view in a list item of a listview

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I am implementing a custom adapter to use in a listview.I am populating the listview with some text messages and one of my classes object. There is an imageview in each list item and on click of that imageview i am showing a view with the objects information and on click of the listview item i am showing a different view. I am able to achieve this but the problem here is that when i click on the imageview the view  that opens up contains the information of some other list items object and not the object contained in the list item whose image view was clicked.I tried a lot to get a solution for this but didnt get one. So i am putting up this question.Please help me.

1. This is the implementation of my custom adapters getView() method-

   ```
       List<Map<String, Object>> data = getTasksData(tasks);
   SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data,
   R.layout.list_item_detail_layout, new String[] { "itemstatus","itemname",         "itemdesc"}, new int[] {R.id.taskPercentage, R.id.taskname, R.id.taskdesc}){
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
   if (convertView == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
      convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_detail_layout, null, false)
   }       
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

   //map object used to populate each list item
   Map<String, Object> listItem = (Map<String, Object>)                                                                   
                                        listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

   //object whose information is to be displayed in the view
   Task task = (Task)listItem.get("item");
   if(task != null){
      activeTask = task;
   }

   //text views to be displayed in each list item
   TextView taskpercentage = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.taskPercentage);
   taskpercentage.setText((String)listItem.get("itemstatus"));

   TextView taskname = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.taskname);
   taskname.setText((String)listItem.get("itemname"));

   TextView taskDescription = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.taskdesc);
   taskDescription.setText((String)listItem.get("itemdesc"));


   //imageview whose click listener has been set to navigate to a view
   ImageView taskEdit = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_edit);
   taskEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

        //method called when image icon on the list view is clicked
        newTask(v, false);
       }
     });
        return convertView;
   }
    };
   ```

   //method which is called when image icon in the list view is clicked
2. newTask(v,false) code -

   ```
   private void newTask(final View view, final boolean isNew) {
      setContentView(R.layout.task_view);

      final EditText taskName = (EditText) this
            .findViewById(R.id.task_name_edtxt);
      if (isNew == false) {
          taskName.setText(activeTask.getName());
      }

   }
   ```

3.ListView Implementation -

```
               listView = ((ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listTaskView));
           listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
               listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {
              Task task = null;
                  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                  Map<String, Object> listItem = (Map<String, Object>) listView
                       .getItemAtPosition(position);
                     task = (Task) listItem.get("item");

                  if (task != null) {
                  activeTask = task;

                 //method called when listview item is clicked
                 showActivityListView(view);
             }
          }
        }
    });
```

1. layout file used as listview item -

   ```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="horizontal" >

             <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/taskPercentage"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_margin="8dp"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                     android:textColor="@color/blue_shade"
                     android:textSize="20sp"
                     android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>

      <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="0px"
            android:paddingRight="5dp" >

      <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/taskname"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:textColor="#FFF38585"
                 android:textSize="15sp" >
            </TextView>
            <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/edit_task"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:src="@drawable/edit_form"/>
       </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/taskdesc"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                 android:textColor="#FF2CE4A4"
                 android:textSize="13sp" >
           </TextView>
      </LinearLayout>

      </LinearLayout>
   ```

this is the implementation reference. Please, if any one can tell me what the problem is or how to get this functionality working correctly, do help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the newTask code as well?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
final ImageView taskEdit = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_edit);
taskEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
     newTask(taskEdit, false);
    }
  });
     return convertView;
}
```

Comment: I tried declaring the imageview as final but it didnt work. I will add some more code snippet of my implementation for reference.Thanks for your support so far.

Answer (score 0):

From your `MainActivity` or your `Fragment`, you should initialize the `ListView` and set its adapter. You should also set `onItemClickListener` in it (`MainActivity`). Then get the `object` of in the given `position` parameter from the list and execute your action based on it.

**Example:**

```
ListView listViewItems = new ListView(this);
    listViewItems.setAdapter(adapter);
    listViewItems.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Click ListItem Number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show();
       }
      });
```

Your can create your own `Object` class and pass it to the list, then check on the item position and perform your action.

I hope it helps

Comment: i have provided some more information, if you can figure out the problem please tel me.

Comment: i have provided some more information, if you can figure out the problem please tel me. by the way i had already implemented the listviews implementation prior to asking this question like you have written in your answer. but that is not the problem. Problem is that I am able to navigate to the desired view but with incorrect information. i.e suppose i have clikced on the list items image view at position three in the listview the value that i get is of the object contained at 6th listitem in the list view.

Comment: one observation from my side by putting some logs is that the getView() method of the adapter class is being called multiple times.

Comment: the view  that opens up when i click on the image view contains the objects information at the same postion as the no of times the getView() method is being called. i.e if getView() method is getting called 6 times while populating the listview then on clikc of the image view contains information of the task object at position 6